# Dataframe Not Getting Updated Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
titanic= pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Shailesh.Rana\\Downloads\\train.csv")
title=[] #to extract titles out of names
for i in range(len(titanic)):
title.append(titanic.loc[:,"Name"].iloc[i].split(" ")[1]) #index 1 is title
titanic.iloc[(np.array(title)=="Master.")&(np.array(titanic.Age.isnull()))].loc[:,"Age"]=3.5 
#values with master title and NAN as age
```

The last line doesn't make a change to the original dataset. In fact, if I run this line again, it still shows a series with 4 NaN values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `str[1]` for select second `list`.

Also convert to `numpy array` is not necessary, `iloc` should be removed too.

```
titanic = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John Master.','Joe','Mary Master.'],
                        'Age':[10,20,np.nan]})

titanic.loc[(titanic.Name.str.split().str[1]=="Master.") &(titanic.Age.isnull()) ,"Age"]=3.5

print (titanic)
    Age          Name
0  10.0  John Master.
1  20.0           Joe
2   3.5  Mary Master.
```

Comment: great, thanks! But why didn't my code work? It didn't show an error.

Comment: Thanks jezrael. This was very helpful. you truly know your Python.